# ImportError: Module use of python37.dll conflicts with this version of Python

Tags: python, python-3.12

I used a virtual enviroment (my _venv) and download the code from the webside to introduce pyaedt
Therefore, the terminal appear some errors

```
PS C:\my_venv\Scripts> .\python 12.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\my_venv\Scripts\12.py", line 28, in <module>
import pyaedt
File "C:\my_venv\Lib\site-packages\pyaedt\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
import pyaedt.downloads as downloads
File "C:\my_venv\Lib\site-packages\pyaedt\downloads.py", line 7, in <module>
from pyaedt.generic.general_methods import is_ironpython
File "C:\my_venv\Lib\site-packages\pyaedt\generic\general_methods.py", line 25, in <module>
from pyaedt.aedt_logger import pyaedt_logger
File "C:\my_venv\Lib\site-packages\pyaedt\aedt_logger.py", line 3, in <module>
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
File "C:\Users\904692\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\logging\handlers.py", line 26, in        <module>
import io, logging, socket, os, pickle, struct, time, re
File "C:\Users\904692\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\socket.py", line 52, in <module>
import _socket
**ImportError: Module use of python37.dll conflicts with this version of Python.**
```

Code

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pyaedt

ansys_version = "2023.2"

aedb_path = os.path.join(pyaedt.generate_unique_folder_name(), pyaedt.generate_unique_name("pcb") +        ".aedb")
edb = pyaedt.Edb(edbpath=aedb_path, edbversion=ansys_version)
print("EDB is located at {}".format(aedb_path))
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to activate the virtual environment? It looks like it tries to use libraries from Python 3.12 (`...Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\socket.py`)